# Prove that for each $n \in \mathbb{N},$ the set $P = \{j/n\}$ is a partition of $[0,1]$

Tags: integration, partitions-for-integration

$$P=\left\{\frac{j}{n}:j=0,1,...n\right\}$$
I can't find anywhere in my book where it is proven that a given set is a partition. It just jumps to showing, using partitions, that a function is integrable over the interval.

Comment: What is the definition of *partition* used in your book? Alternatively, which book are you using?

Comment: Usually a partition of a set is a family of pairwise disjoint subsets (or whose interiors are disjoint) that cover the set (the union is or contains the set). Now, define $I_j = [(j-1)/n,j/n]$ and you are done, it is obvious.

Comment: an intorduction to analysis by william r wade

Comment: Im not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

Any finite set of points 
$$
a = x_1 < x_2 < \cdots < x_n = b
$$
defines a partition of the interval $[a,b]$. In some contexts when discussing integration the partition might be described by the set of subintervals $[x_i, x_{i+1}]$ but the essential meaning is the same.

Those subintervals don't strictly partition the whole interval, since they are not disjoint (they share endpoints) but that does not matter when using partitions to define integrals.

Comment: Why does it not matter? Explain please o_0 Intervals are sets too, so partitioning of intervals should satisfy the definition of partitioning of sets, no?

Comment: @William The partition into intervals when defining integrals need not exactly match the definition of a set partition because the purpose (integration) does not need that match. What matters for integration are the values of the function at the division points and the lengths of the intervals, not the subsets themselves. Mathematicians often allow themselves a little flexibility in the use of terms like "partition" in order to make exposition clearest in each context.